# How can I reset the initial value of JetpackCompose AnimatedFloat, when I restart the animation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an `AnimatedFloat` that I created using

```
val animatedFloat = animatedFloat(0f)
```

I start the animation using

```
animatedFloat.animateTo(
        targetValue = 1f,
        anim = repeatable(
                iterations = AnimationConstants.Infinite,
                animation = tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing),
        )
)
```

All these works and it starts to move from 0f to 1f in 2 seconds.

When I stop it using the below, it stops well.

```
animatedFloat.stop()
```

However when I restart it using the same `animateTo` function i.e.

```
animatedFloat.animateTo(
        targetValue = 1f,
        anim = repeatable(
                iterations = AnimationConstants.Infinite,
                animation = tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing),
        )
)
```

It doesn't start from 0f anymore. It starts from the value where it previously stopped. Not only that, it will take the same amount of time from where it previously stop to the targetValue
e.g. if it stop at 0.7f, then it will take 2s to start from `0.7f` to `1.0f`, which slows down the rate of change.

How can I reset the `initialValue` after stopping it?

Answer (score 4):

The `stop` function simply stops the animation, it doesn't reset the value.
You can use `animatedFloat.snapTo(0f)` to set the value to 0f immediately without any animation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/AnimatedFloat#snapto

Comment: Nice. This works. Just feel strange that the subsequent start animation, the initial value was set to the previously stop last value, and slow the animation rate. Feel it might be a bug.

Comment: Yeah I had the same problem a couple of days ago. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/BaseAnimatedValue#stop) is says that the animation is stopped in its track so I guess it's not a bug

Comment: However my use case is to pause and resume the animation but I haven't figured that out yet

Comment: Stop at where it is, that's fine. The issue is, the rate from where it initial value is changed to where it stop, i.e. the next iteration, it start from where it stop e.g. 0.7 instead of the original initial value e.g. 0.

Pause and resume as per your need will be a problem.

Comment: Yeah I'll have to use something else instead of the `animatedValue` functions

Comment: Ya. As long as we don't depend on the value, that should be fine.

Comment: agreed, when I want to restore previous value with animate.value. it will always doubled the duration which seems like a bug. How to achieve if i want retain the previous value ?

Comment: Ah, awkward. I'd like to use this from finishedListener, but I can't call a method on the state object at that point because I'm still defining it. Back to the drawing board, LOL

Answer (score 0):

`AnimatedFloat` is designed around fluidity. It assumes that in most cases it's undesirable to *skip* to a different value. That's why it stops where it is, and picks up from where it was stopped the next time `animateTo` is called. Could you share your use cases for pausing/resuming the animations?

Comment: There's at least one obvious use case for skipping to a different value. Consider the case where the animated variable represents a rotation. When you get to 360.0f, you'd like to snap that back to 0.0f so you can continue rotating in the same direction without the risk of precision errors. This is exactly the issue I have at the moment - when I flip a card from front to back, it animates from 0 to 180. Works fine. When I flip it from back to front, it animates from 180 to 360. Then if I flip it from front to back again, it tries to animate to 180, which flips in the wrong direction.